# Can European Children attend public or private school in the US?

Tags: usa, study

My sister and nephews are coming to the USA to visit me for almost 90 days, and we would like my older nephew (6 years old) be able to go to school. We would like him to interact with other children and learn basic stuff. I am not sure if he could assist to any public or private school while they are visiting us. They are coming from Spain with the ESTA visa. Any information would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: (I think the verb you're looking for is 'attend', not 'assist' -- especially if you're translating the Spanish *asistir*...)

Answer (score 5):

Research local schools in your neighborhood. Figure out what schools are there and what programs they have. There are many that have bi-lingual or English as a second language programs. Ideal would be so-called "two way" program: half of the kids are native English speaker, the other half is native Spanish and the instruction language alternates every months or so.

Once you find something that may be a good fit, just go over there and ask. Have a conversation and see where it goes. If you don't like the answer from a particular school try another one. You may have to sort out insurance, liability, transportation, food, etc.

We have done this the other way around: US kids attending a public school in Europe for a while. The school just said: "Sure, no problem" and it was a good experience for all parties involved. There is more school to school variability in the US, so you may have to try a few different ones.

Comment: It may also be necessary to look into visa restrictions, which the school may or may not know about.  I have not yet found anything stating that VWP visitors are allowed to attend elementary schools.

Comment: Related/possible duplicate: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87160/can-my-child-attend-a-private-school-whilst-im-on-usa-esta

Comment: And in some cases non-immigrants may be required to pay tuition to the school despite it being public, and schools cannot waive this requirement.

Comment: There are two different issues here. Public K-12 schools in the US cannot legally deny enrollment or charge more fee to enroll based on the student's immigration status. But that does not mean that attending public school isn't a violation of the person's status -- for some statuses it is a violation of status to attend school full-time.